# Rails/Paperclip Errno::EACCESS (Permission denied)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, permission-denied

I'm working on Rails app with Paperclip gem used to save users' avatars. Production environment, FreeBSD, Apache, MySQL.

When saving user profile with an avatar file specified - the Permission denied errors appears.

I set 777 permission to all Paperclip directories - it didn't help.

Please help!

Thanks!

config/environments/production.rb

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/local/bin'
```

app/models/user.rb

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x180>", :thumb => "40x40>" }
```

Comment: is it 777 for all users?

Comment: Show your paperclip configuration.

Comment: > is it 777 for all users? - yes, of course! the last `7` means rwx for everyone

Comment: added paperclip configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is quite simple (as always). Change the owner of the public directory to www (was root):

$ chown -R www public

Comment: I was having the same problems, tried your solution, and I got this: % chown -R www public
chown: public/system: Operation not permitted

Comment: Maybe you missed the `sudo` ?